# React Native APK release

Tags: android, android-studio, react-native

I'm trying to build a Singed apk using android studio. I'm using react-native. As new to this field I actually can not find how to make it. I just run it from terminal and it just builds from there.

What are the process for building a Signed apk using react-native.

Answer (score 4):

The [React Native Documentation for Generating a Signed APK](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android.html) is fairly comprehensive and should answer your question.

Be careful when generating your `keystore` - if you lose this you won't be able to upload updates to Google Play.

Answer (score 0):

Follow this guide to sign your APK: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android.html#adding-signing-config-to-your-app-s-gradle-config

Run `./gradlew assembleRelease` on android folder and your signed APK will be compiled in `android/app/build/outputs/apk`.