# React native Google Play is app purchased

Tags: android, google-play, react-native

I'm new to react native and Google play and I'm writing an app the will use a rest server to get data.

I need to know how can I be sure that only purchased app can access to the rest server.

Thanks!!

Comment: Implement some verification like Google auth(firebase) to verify

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React Native APK release](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40763972/react-native-apk-release)